How to get an exception from SpamHaus "Policy Blocklist" (PBL)?
Much as I love the speed and bandwidth of Verizon FiOS, I absolutely hate the fact, that they disallowed the use of their own SMTP-relay (unless you have @verizon.net in the From-field).
And then they added the entire 100.1.48.0/22 block to the SpamHaus PBL. I suppose, this makes sense overall: Most of the users are happy to use GMail et al, so if their computers speak SMTP, it must be spam…
But SpamHaus talks about a possibility of creating an exception:

Run your own mail server?
If you run your own mail server, and require removal from the PBL, please click on “More Info” to review your ISP’s policy. Once you have reviewed the policy, please tick the “I am running my own mail server” check-box at the bottom of the page to enable removal.

Unfortunately, that button — the "I am running my own mail server” — is not there (even with ad-blocker completely disabled).
Did SpamHaus change their policy regarding these exceptions — and forgot to update the verbiage — or is it a web-page bug?
How would I ask SpamHaus to exclude myself from their listing?

You're asking how to ask a company to do something for you? Contact them and talk to them, they'll let you know, isn't this the most optimal way always?

SpamHaus is not exactly a company in a usual sense -- and I thought, other "superusers" have already had experience dealing with them...

It's not even the correct website to ask about a web service in the 1st place. But they have an easy to fill form on their website for stuff like these from what I see.
